# Calling a SQL Server stored procedure from Visual Foxpro 9

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro

I have been trying to call a SQL Server stored procedure that has no parameters and no return values. All it does is recalculate data in a SQL Server database.

I thought I could use something simple like

```
lsqlcmd = " execute  storedprocname"
```

but the procedure is not being called and I am not receiving an errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know that it is not being called? Did you check aerror()? If it doesn't error then it should be working.

Comment: That all by itself just sets a text variable to be that command, but does absolute nothing otherwise. Show how are actually running the command on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling it in SQLEXEC()?  This how I've seen it done:

```
TEXT TO lcSQLCommand
    <database>.<schema>.<sproc>
ENDTEXT

gcConnectionString = [Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=] + "<servername>" + [;Database=] + "<database>" + [;Trusted_Connection=yes]
STORE SQLSTRINGCONNECT(gcConnectionString) TO gnConnHandle

SQLEXEC(gnConnHandle, lcSQLCommand)
```

You'll need to update the connection string to however your database is configured, this was for windows authentication.